Is there an easier way to do timed animations in Actionscript 2?
So, im currently making a tamagotchi style game in Macromedia Flash 8, and i need for the current pet to change animations depending on certain actions, and keep in that way for an amount of frames, here is what i came up with:
var animSpriteBody = 1;
var animSpriteFace = 1;
var animBegin = true;
var animFrames = 0;
var animLoop = 0;
var animCurrent = "default";
var animName = "default";
var animNext = "default";
//
function animation() {
    if (animBegin) {
        switch (animName) {
        case "default" :
            animSpriteBody = 1;
            animSpriteFace = 1;
            animFrames = 0;
            animNext = "default";
            break;
        case "petHead" :
            animSpriteBody = 1;
            animSpriteFace = 4;
            animFrames = 30;
            animNext = "default";
            break;
        case "petBody" :
            animSpriteBody = 6;
            animSpriteFace = 1;
            animFrames = 90;
            animNext = "default";
            break;
        }
    }
}
//
function animate() {
    if (animBegin) {
        pet.body.gotoAndStop(animSpriteBody);
        pet.face.gotoAndStop(animSpriteFace);
        animLoop = animFrames;
        animCurrent = animName;
        animBegin = false;
    }
    if (animLoop != 0) {
        animLoop--;
        if (animCurrent != animName) {
            animLoop = 0;
            animBegin = true;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        animName = animNext;
        animBegin = true;
        break;
    }
}
//
//
//
function onEnterFrame() {
    animation();
    animate();
}

So, what it does is, every single frame it plays the "default" animation, but if the variable "animName" changes, it plays that animation for an amount of time defined, then plays the next animation defined, and it goes on until it changes back to "default".
All i want to know is, is this too much? Because im really a noob in AS2 and i dont know if there a more efficient way...
I really tried to optimize this code, but every time i did, the pet just got stuck in a single animation or got crazy and changed animations rapidly.

Keep in mind that my AS2 is really (REALLY!) rusty as the language itself is more than 15 years as obsolete, and the scripts below might not work as is, but the principles should be solid.
So, you need to make one animation run for given number of frames and then revert to the default state. It is probably not THAT difficult:
var targetClip: MovieClip = pet.face;
var basicFrame: Number = 1;
var framesLeft: Number = 0;

function onEnterFrame(): void
{
    if (targetClip._currentframe == basicFrame)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    framesLeft -= 1;
    
    if (framesLeft < 1)
    {
        animate(basicFrame, 0);
    }
}

function animate(frame: Number, count: Number): void
{
    framesLeft = count;
    targetClip.gotoAndStop(frame);
}

Using this, since we are addressing a single target, is really simple:
function playAnimation(name: String): void
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "default":
            animate(1, 0);
            break;
        case "petHead":
            animate(4, 30);
            break;
        case "petBody":
            animate(1, 0);
            break;
    }
}

Now, the problem is, there are TWO body parts that have to do this. They should act exactly the same, but they are distinct.
The most obvious and straightforward approach to this would be to create an exact replica of the variables and methods to control the other part, but what if there are 5 of them? 10? 100?
Replicating the same code 100 times does not seem like a sensible thing to do, right? If only there was a way to encapsulate these variables and methods into some kind of typical contained that would only need to be addressed once and then does the rest on its own!
The thing you are looking for is OOP — Object Oriented Programming. It allows to convert the code above into a sort of black box and you can create as many these black boxes as the body parts you need to control:
class BodyPart
{
    // Encapsulated variables.
    private var targetClip: MovieClip = null;
    private var basicFrame: Number = 1;
    private var framesLeft: Number = 0;
    
    // This is constructor. It is called when you create each black box.
    function BodyPart(target)
    {
        targetClip = target;
        
        // This is (probably) the way to address
        // the black box from the body part.
        targetClip.controller = this;
        
        // Since onEnterFrame handler works in MovieClips only,
        // we are going to use that to make it work.
        targetClip.onEnterFrame = onEnterFrame;
    }
    
    private function onEnterFrame(): void
    {
        // As it is called from the MovieClip, "this" variable points
        // to the MovieClip rather then to the BodyPart instance.
        // But we've left a sign there, right?
        var self: BodyPart = this.controller;
        
        // Call the black box method.
        self.onFrame();
        
        // P.S. I am not really sure. The point is, we need to get back
        // to the BodyPart context to be able to access the variables,
        // because they are not in the MovieClip and not available there.
        // If this does not work, you should figure this out on your own.
    }
    
    private function onFrame(): void
    {
        // We are inside the black box now,
        // and its fields (instance variables) should be
        // normally available just by referencing them.
        if (targetClip._currentframe == basicFrame)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        framesLeft -= 1;
        
        if (framesLeft < 1)
        {
            animate(basicFrame, 0);
        }
    }
    
    // Aaaaand, finally, the interface method.
    public function animate(frame: Number, count: Number): void
    {
        framesLeft = count;
        targetClip.gotoAndStop(frame);
    }
}

That was the class. The classes are different from the frame scripts. You should figure out how to work with them, but as far as I remember you are to create a file named "class_name.as" (in our case it would be "BodyPart.as", yes, case-sensitive) and put it to the same folder where your main *.fla file is.
Now, how to use it:
// This instructs Flash that we are going to use an external class.
import BodyPart;

// Create black boxes for all the body parts.
var Bo: BodyPart = new BodyPart(pet.body);
var Fa: BodyPart = new BodyPart(pet.face);

// Now for each of the part you have an instance of the BodyPart class,
// and each instance has an independent and encapsulated set of
// variables and methods, that run on their own.

function playAnimation(name: String): void
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "default":
            Fa.animate(1, 0);
            Bo.animate(1, 0);
            break;
        case "petHead":
            Fa.animate(4, 30);
            Bo.animate(1, 0);
            break;
        case "petBody":
            Fa.animate(1, 0);
            Bo.animate(6, 90);
            break;
    }
}

P.S. I am not really sure (remember, 15 years, rusty) but it is possible that there is a simple way to access the onEnterFrame(...) functionality in the class: to make it a subclass of the MovieClip class. Might just work:
class BodyPart extends MovieClip
{
    // Encapsulated variables.
    // ...
    
    // Constructor
    function BodyPart(target)
    {
        targetClip = target;
    }
    
    // If I am right this will be invoked once per frame just like that.
    private function onEnterFrame(): void
    {
        if (targetClip._currentframe == basicFrame)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        framesLeft -= 1;
        
        if (framesLeft < 1)
        {
            animate(basicFrame, 0);
        }
    }
    
    // The rest of the class.


So, what you're telling me to do is to make a class file, where in that class file i can basically adress any part of the character, then animate it, if im understaing it correctly, thats basically thats all i actually wanted! I know its advised not to comment just because of this but really thanks man! (And yes i know AS2 is very ancient, im just using it to goof around and make games for Newgrounds)

With OOP/classes you can createbehaviors, and then apply same behaviors to many things without multiplying the amount of code. There's a better (but more advanced) version of it, actually: you can attach behaviors directly to the said body parts (Library -> symbol properties -> Linkage) so that the instances of symbols (namely pet.face and pet.body) will have the method animate(...) themselves.
